# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pin' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

I have been working on making a website just like Pinterest and I am now working on Searching functionality with 'login_required' decorator. The view is not yet finished since I build this as I check whether the request goes through smoothly with Postman. However, the request doesn't even get to the first line of code in the view because I keep getting this error. Below is what I see when I test it with python debugger.

```
-> return func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
(Pdb) n
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pin' referenced before assignment
> /Users/woohyunan/projects/Wecode/pinterrorist-backend/pin/views.py(38)wrapper()
```

Below is the SearchView part of the whole views.py:

```
class SearchView(View):

    @login_required
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        body        = json.loads(request.body)
        user        = kwargs['user']
        user_id     = kwargs['user_id']
        search_term = request.POST.get('search', None)

        return JsonResponse({'search_term': search_term})
```

and below is the decorator:

```
def login_required(func):
        def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            header_token            = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
            decoded_token           = jwt.decode(header_token, SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')['id']
            user                    = User.objects.get(id=decoded_token)
            user_id                 = user.id
            kwargs['user']          = user
            kwargs['user_id']       = user_id

            try:
                if User.objects.filter(id=decoded_token).exists():
                    return func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({"message": "THE USER DOES NOT EXIST"})
            except jwt.DecodeError:
                return JsonResponse({"message": "WRONG_TOKEN!"}, status=403)
            except KeyError:
                return JsonResponse({"message": "KEY ERROR"}, status=405)
            except User.objects.filter(email=decoded_token).DoesNotExist:
                return JsonResponse({"message": "USER NOT FOUND"}, status=406)
        return wrapper
```

If you need some more detail about this mysterious variable "pin", below is the whole views.py:

```
import boto3
import json
import jwt

from django.shortcuts       import render
from django.views           import View
from django.http            import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from django.forms.models    import model_to_dict
from django.core            import serializers
from django.db.models       import Q

from pin.models         import (
    Topic,
    UserTopic,
    Board,
    Pin,
    Topic,
    PinUser,
    PinTopic,
    Comment
)
from account.models         import User, Follow, Social
from pinterrorist.settings  import S3URL, SECRET_KEY

def login_required(func):
        def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            header_token            = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
            decoded_token           = jwt.decode(header_token, SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')['id']
            user                    = User.objects.get(id=decoded_token)
            user_id                 = user.id
            kwargs['user']          = user
            kwargs['user_id']       = user_id

            try:
                if User.objects.filter(id=decoded_token).exists():
                    return func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({"message": "THE USER DOES NOT EXIST"})
            except jwt.DecodeError:
                return JsonResponse({"message": "WRONG_TOKEN!"}, status=403)
            except KeyError:
                return JsonResponse({"message": "KEY ERROR"}, status=405)
            except User.objects.filter(email=decoded_token).DoesNotExist:
                return JsonResponse({"message": "USER NOT FOUND"}, status=406)
        return wrapper

class IntroTopicView(View):
    @login_required
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user        = kwargs['user']
        user_id     = kwargs['user_id']
        topiclst        = list(Topic.objects.values())
        return JsonResponse({"topics": topiclst})

    @login_required
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        body            = json.loads(request.body)
        user            = kwargs['user']
        user_id         = kwargs['user_id']
        chosen_topics   = body['chosen_topics']
        for topic in chosen_topics:
            user.topics.add(topic)
        return JsonResponse({'chosen_topics': chosen_topics}, status=200)

class MyPageView(View):
    @login_required
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        # receive the user object from the decorator
        user        = kwargs['user']
        user_id     = kwargs['user_id']
        # receive the user's interested topics
        pins = []
        topics      = user.topics.all()
        for topic in topics:
            for pin in Pin.objects.filter(topic=topic):
                pins.append(pin)
        pin_user_data = serializers.serialize('json', pin.user.all())
        pins_detail = [{"image":pin.image_url, "text1":pin.paragraph1, "text2":pin.paragraph2, "users": pin_user_data} for pin in pins]
        return JsonResponse({"pins" : pins_detail})

class CommentView(View):
    @login_required
    def post(self, request, pin, **kwargs):
        user        = kwargs['user']
        user_id     = kwargs['user_id']
        pin_id      = pin
        body        = json.loads(request.body)
        comment     = body['comment']
        pin         = Pin.objects.get(id=pin_id)

        new_comment             = Comment.objects.create(content=comment, pin=pin, user=user)
        pin_comment             = pin.comments.all()
        try:
            pin_comment_info    = [{"user": comment.user.email.split("@")[0], "comment": model_to_dict(comment)} for comment in pin_comment]
        except AttributeError:
            pin_comment_info    = [{"user": comment.user.social_id, "comment": model_to_dict(comment)} for comment in pin_comment]

        comment_len             = len(pin_comment)
        pin_user_data           = serializers.serialize('json', pin.user.all())

        return JsonResponse({"pin": {"id": pin.id, "image_url": pin.image_url, "text1": pin.paragraph1, "text2": pin.paragraph2, "users": pin_user_data}, "comment": pin_comment_info, "comment_total": comment_len})

    @login_required
    def delete(self, request, pin, **kwargs):
        user        = kwargs['user']
        user_id     = kwargs['user_id']
        pin_id      = pin
        body        = json.loads(request.body)
        comment_id  = body['comment_id']
        pin         = Pin.objects.get(id=pin_id)

        Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id).delete()
        pin_comment             = pin.comments.all()
        try:
            pin_comment_info    = [{"user": comment.user.email.split("@")[0], "comment": model_to_dict(comment)} for comment in pin_comment]
        except AttributeError:
            pin_comment_info    = [{"user": comment.user.social_id, "comment": model_to_dict(comment)} for comment in pin_comment]

        comment_len             = len(pin_comment)
        pin_user_data           = serializers.serialize('json', pin.user.all())

        return JsonResponse({"pin": {"id": pin.id, "image_url": pin.image_url, "text1": pin.paragraph1, "text2": pin.paragraph2, "users": pin_user_data}, "comment": pin_comment_info, "comment_total": comment_len})

    @login_required
    def get(self, request, pin, **kwargs):
        user        = kwargs['user']
        user_id     = kwargs['user_id']

        pin_id = pin
        pin = Pin.objects.get(id=pin_id)
        pin_comment             = pin.comments.all()
        try:
            pin_comment_info    = [{"user": comment.user.email.split("@")[0], "comment": model_to_dict(comment)} for comment in pin_comment]
        except AttributeError:
            pin_comment_info    = [{"user": comment.user.social_id, "comment": model_to_dict(comment)} for comment in pin_comment]

        comment_len             = len(pin_comment)
        pin_user_data           = serializers.serialize('json', pin.user.all())

        return JsonResponse({"pin": {"id": pin.id, "image_url": pin.image_url, "text1": pin.paragraph1, "text2": pin.paragraph2, "users": pin_user_data}, "comment": pin_comment_info, "comment_total": comment_len})

class PinView(View):
    @login_required
    def get(self, request, pin, **kwargs):
        user        = kwargs['user']
        user_id     = kwargs['user_id']

        pin_id = pin
        pin = Pin.objects.get(id=pin_id)
        pin_comment             = pin.comments.all()
        try:
            pin_comment_info    = [{"user": comment.user.email.split("@")[0], "comment": model_to_dict(comment)} for comment in pin_comment]
        except AttributeError:
            pin_comment_info    = [{"user": comment.user.social_id, "comment": model_to_dict(comment)} for comment in pin_comment]

        comment_len             = len(pin_comment)
        pin_user_data           = serializers.serialize('json', pin.user.all())

        return JsonResponse({"pin": {"id": pin.id, "image_url": pin.image_url, "text1": pin.paragraph1, "text2": pin.paragraph2, "users": pin_user_data}, "comment": pin_comment_info, "comment_total": comment_len})

class SearchView(View):

    @login_required
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        body        = json.loads(request.body)
        user        = kwargs['user']
        user_id     = kwargs['user_id']
        search_term = request.POST.get('search', None)

        return JsonResponse({'search_term': search_term})
```

How do I get rid of this error? I have tried everything but it's not going away...

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: maybe this one... ` pin.user.all()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```py
pin_user_data = serializers.serialize('json', pin.user.all())
```

This line is out of the loop. So your 'pin' may not be defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hopefully I will become as detail-oriented/error catching as you soon.